# How to create a top menu bar using quasar-framework

Tags: vuejs2, quasar-framework

I'm trying the Quasar framework, there's nothing in the demos or in the currently live websites (in: https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-awesome) that shows that shows how a top-menu bar is used in the framework  for, which I think is something standard in most web framework. Please help.

Answer (score 2):

Since quasar is PWA framework for building apps that's why it does not support. Still, you can tweak a bit and have the button on the top.

```
<q-toolbar-title>
  <q-btn></q-btn>
</q-toolbar-title>
```

You can also add popover inside the button to make a drop-down button.

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar in one of my projects. It will display menu items inline on large screens and as popup for smaller screens. You can modify the layout to your requirements.

```
<template> 
   <q-layout>
     <q-layout-header >
      <q-toolbar>
        <q-btn
          flat
          dense
          round
          aria-label="Menu"
          @click="leftDrawerOpen = !leftDrawerOpen" >
          <q-icon name="menu" />
        </q-btn>
        <img
          class="ml-2"
          height="30"
          alt="Company logo"
          src="~assets/logo.png"
        >
        <q-btn
          :color="showActions?'secondary':''"
          :icon="showActions?'keyboard_arrow_up':'keyboard_arrow_down'"
          flat
          class="lt-sm ml-auto"
          @click.native="showActions = !showActions"
        />


        <div class="action-buttons ml-auto gt-xs" >
          <q-btn
            v-for="item in toolbarButtons"
            :key="item.label"
            :icon="item.icon"
            :label="item.label"
            flat
            @click="item.action()"
          />
        </div>
      </q-toolbar>
      <div class="row justify-end">
        <div class="col-7" >
          <q-popover
            :anchor-click="true"
            v-model="showActions"
            fit
            anchor="bottom left"
            class="lt-sm"
          >
            <q-list
              separator
              link>
              <q-item
                v-close-overlay
                v-for="item in toolbarButtons"
                :key="item.label"
                @click.native="item.action()"
              >
                <q-item-side >
                  <q-icon :name="item.icon"/>
                </q-item-side>
                {{ item.label }}
              </q-item>
            </q-list>
          </q-popover>
        </div>
      </div>
     </q-layout-header>
   </q-layout>
  </template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'LayoutName',
  data() {
    return {
      leftDrawerOpen: false,
      showActions: false,
      toolbarButtons: [
        {
          label: 'Share',
          icon: 'fa fa-share',
          action: () => {
            this.$router.push('/import');
          },
        },
        {
          label: 'Save',
          icon: 'fa fa-save',
          action: () => {
          },
        },
        ...
      ],
    };
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: will give a try. Are you currently using this on production?

Comment: Yes. I  use it in a production hybrid app using cordova  and electron